# Center image inside div vertically on any screen

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="container">   
<main>
    <div class="half"><img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aiga-symbol-signs/441/aiga_cashier-512.png" alt="Smiley face" width="20%" style="margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: auto;  vertical-align: middle;"></div>   

    <div class="half2"></div>
    <div class="half2"></div>
</main>
```

And this CSS:

```
main {
height: calc(100%);
background: green;
}
.half {
height: 40%;
}
.half2 {
height: 30%;
}
.half2:nth-child(2) {
background: pink;
}
.half2:last-child {
background: yellow;
}
```

I want to dynamically center an image inside each child of the main elements, vertically and horizontally. I can center it horizontally, however the code won't work vertically.

Comment: A useful guide for centering: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html